# How to invoke a POST web api when a file arrives in azure blob storage, and post the file to the api?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have video files arriving into Azure blob storage.

When the file arrives, I want to invoke a REST api and pass the file in the api's POST method.

What is the Azure blob storage setting where-in I can configure the api call trigger (when new file arrives) and specify that the file needs to be POST'ed?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Azure blob storage setting where-in I can configure the
> api call trigger (when new file arrives) and specify that the file
> needs to be POST'ed?

There are many ways to accomplish this.

One possible solution is to make use of [`Blob Triggered Azure Function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp). The Function will be triggered when a blob is created. In your Function code, you can invoke your API and post the blob data.

Other option would be to use [`Azure Logic Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=consumption) where you can define a workflow that gets invoked when a blob is created.